# New in Objective C. Simple bug at runtime. Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, overriding

I am learning Objective C and I have tried to override my superclass (NSObject) description method in my BNRItem class. Though it seems like I have done everything right, my NSLog does not seem to use my overridden description method. Instead I see a Thread 1 Breakpoint 1.1 in my definition of the description method and more precisely, where I defined the descriptionString.

Here is my console output.

```
2015-08-30 20:49:00.622 RandomItems[46034:1002101] Zero
2015-08-30 20:49:00.623 RandomItems[46034:1002101] One
2015-08-30 20:49:00.623 RandomItems[46034:1002101] Two
2015-08-30 20:49:00.623 RandomItems[46034:1002101] Three
(lldb)
```

My main.m file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRItem.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    // Create a mutable array object, store its address in items variable...
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Send the message addObject: to the NSMutableArray pointed
    //by the variable item, passing a string each time
    [items addObject:@"One"];
    [items addObject: @"Two"];
    [items addObject: @"Three"];


    // Send another message, insertObject:atIndex;, to that same array object
    [items insertObject:@"Zero" atIndex:0];




    // For every item in the items array ...
    for (NSString *item in items){
        //Log the description of item
        NSLog(@"%@", item);

    }
    // Create a BNRItem instance and log its instance variables in the console

    BNRItem *item = [[BNRItem alloc] init];

    // Set item name to Red Sofa

    item.itemName = @"Red Sofa";
    item.serialNumber= @"A1B2C";
    item.valueInDollards = 100;

    // 
    NSLog(@"%@", item);



    //Destroy the mutable array object
    items = nil ;
}
return 0;
}
```

My header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BNRItem : NSObject

 {
NSString *_itemName;
NSString *_serialNumber;
int _valueInDollards;
NSDate *_dateCreated;
 }

- (void)setItemName:(NSString *)str;
- (NSString *)itemName;

- (void)setSerialNumber:(NSString *)str;
- (NSString *)serialNumber;

- (void)setValueInDollards:(int)v;
- (int)valueInDollards;

- (NSDate *)dateCreated;


@end
```

And finally, my implementation file:

```
 #import "BNRItem.h"

 @implementation BNRItem


- (void)setItemName:(NSString *)str
 {
_itemName = str;
 }


 - (NSString *)itemName
 {
 return _itemName;
 }



- (void)setSerialNumber:(NSString *)str
{
_serialNumber = str;

}
- (NSString *)serialNumber
{
return _serialNumber;
}



- ( void )setValueInDollards:(int)v
{
_valueInDollards = v;

}
- ( int )valueInDollards
{
return _valueInDollards;
}




-( NSDate * )dateCreated
{
return _dateCreated;
}

- ( NSString * )description
{
NSString *descriptionString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ (%@): Worth %d, recorded on %@", self.itemName, self.serialNumber,     self.valueInDollards, self.dateCreated];
return descriptionString;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have simply set a breakpoint on a line in your `-description` method. The debugger is stopping your program at the breakpoint. There's no indication of an actual error.

If you hit the continue button in Xcode, your program would probably proceed just fine.

You can disable the breakpoint, tell Xcode to ignore all breakpoints, or delete the breakpoint if you don't want to break there. The breakpoint will look like a blue arrow in the margins to the left of your code. Right-click or Control-click on it to see options.

To make Xcode ignore breakpoints, toggle the breakpoint button in the debugging toolbar. It also looks like a right-pointing arrow. It will be filled in blue if breakpoints are enabled. It will be an outline if they're disabled.